# Facebook Graph API - Search for posts made by me or a specific user in a group

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, search

Good morning, I researched a lot and I did not find the answer, so I decided to publish it here. Using the **Facebook Graph API**, I need to list the posts of a public group, until then without problems, I can do so [https://graph.facebook.com/2.10/{group-id}/feed](https://graph.facebook.com/2.10/%7Bgroup-id%7D/feed), but the query gets very long Why list all posts, I need to list only my posts in te group (app user). Is there any way to filter this search only for posts created by me or by some specific user through his id, for example?

Comment: there is no api for that

Comment: hi luschn, Is it not possible to do this using the Facebook Graph API? Can not use the 'q' parameter to filter my posts in any way?

Comment: what q parameter? you need to be more specific. what is or isn´t possible with the api can be found in the docs, there is only a q parameter for the search api and you can search FOR groups with it, not search IN groups.

Comment: Being more specific, I need to list the posts I've made in a group. I do not need other people's posts. It's possible?

Comment: again, there is no api for that